# Segmentation fault at writing the telephone number program

Tags: c, string, segmentation-fault, scanf

I am writing a C program that prompts the user to enter a telephone number in the form (xxx)xxx-xxxx and then displays the number in the format xxx.xxx.xxxx. Here is an example:

```
Enter a phone number [(xxx) xxx-xxxx]: (404)817-6200
You entered the data 404.817.6200
```

I created two strings, one for storing the phone number with parenthesis and '-' signs and the other, empty. I want to add each character to the empty string, changing the ')' and '-' to '.'. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void){
    char num[15];
    char phone[13];

    int i = 1;
    int j = 0;
    printf("Please, enter your phone number in the format (xxx)xxx-xxxx:");
    scanf("\n%s", num);
    while(num != '\0'){
        if(num[i] == ')' || num[i] == '-'){
            phone[j] = '.';
        }else{
            phone[j] = num[i];
        }
        i++;
        j++;
        
    }
    printf("\n%s",phone);
}
```

When I run the program, it gives me the error message that says:

```
Segmentation fault
```

Can somebody explain why it is happening and how to prevent it in the future?

Comment: `while(num != '\0')` -> `while(num[i] != '\0')`

Comment: It worked! Can you explain it?

Comment: @RomanMukosieiev your compiler should have warned you. `num` is the array, but you want just _one_  element of the array.

Comment: You're not copying the null terminator to `phone`.

Comment: As for why that worked, it's the same reason that you do `num[i] == ')'`

Comment: Thank you for all the responses.
Yes, I am not replacing the '(', because I am skipping the first character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see three issues in your program:

(1) `while(num != '\0')` should be `while(num[i] != '\0'`. `num` is an array (and will never compare equal `'\0'`, so you get an endless loop and exceed array bounds.

(2) you need at least 14 bytes for `phone` (just one less than num, not two less)

(3) you need to write a string termination character into `phone`; othwerwise `printf("\n%s",phone);` will again exceed the bounds of `phone`; e.g:

```
}
phone[j] = '\0';
printf("\n%s",phone);`
```

Comment: If the output is, indeed, *always* of the `xxx.xxx.xxxx` format, then 13 is sufficient size for `phone` ... and `num` need only be 14.

Answer (score 0):

When you reference the name of an array variable in C, without appending the `[]` (index) operator, you are (effectively) referring to the *address* of that array's first element. This will never be zero (or `NULL`) for an array declared as a local variable, so the comparison of `num` to zero (`'\0'`) in your `while` loop will *never* be true, and the loop will run on unstopped, until you try to read or write to an invalid address, at which point the program will crash.

With compiler warnings enabled, you should see something like the following (generated by clang-cl):

> warning : comparing a pointer to a null character constant; did you
> mean to compare to NULL? [-Wpointer-compare]
>  warning : comparison
> of array 'num' not equal to a null pointer is always true
> [-Wtautological-pointer-compare]

What you should do, instead, is to compare the 'current' element (at index `i`) to the `nul` character (`'\0'`) to check for the end of the string:

```c
    while (num[i] != '\0') {// Check character at position "i"
        // rest of your loop ...
```

You should also ensure that your `phone` string is properly `nul`-terminated (although some compilers will initialize the array to zero, don't rely on this). You can do this either by adding an initializer to the declaration of `phone`:

```c
    char phone[13] = { 0 }; // Will set all elements to zero
```

or by adding the `nul` terminator *immediately* after the end of your `while` loop:

```c
        // body of while loop
        // ...
    }
    phone[j] = '\0'; // Append the terminator
```